# lighttpd in Amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3, lighttpd

Im planning to host my site in Amazon s3. Is it possible to stream videos using lighttpd streaming server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon S3 provides it's own server so if you're using Amazon S3 you can't use lighttpd.

If you want to use Lighttpd, you may want to look at Amazon EC2 to run your own virtual server.

Regardless, you CAN use Amazon Web Services to stream video by using Amazon S3 to store the files, and Amazon Cloudfront to stream them using RTMP.   You can also stream video files using progressive download using S3 by itself.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you reply. Actually I need to protect my videos from being downloaded. So how can i protect my videos, if i host it in Amazon s3?   URL Expiring concept is the only solution???

Comment: I would recommend using the RTMP streaming.  It's much harder to capture that way, and most people won't be able to easly download it.  

Of course nothing on the web can be completely protected with this simple and inexpensive of a solution, but DRM is not cheap, and it's a matter of how much you're willing to invest to protect against the risk.